# time zone issue with fromnow() moment.js

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I have been using moment.js to display the comment/reply time in the SharePoint. There seems to be a time Zone issue.
When few items are updated only a couple of seconds or minutes ago, due to timezone issue, the last updated time is shown with the difference in timezone. For example, when commented on an article where the comment must show 'a few seconds ago' while it shows '4 hours ago'

Comment: Please include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install moment
--------------------
var moment = require('moment');
moment().format();
moment().startOf('hour').fromNow();       
// an hour ago
see the examples 
https://momentjs.com/
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please explain why your answer solves the question and what your code does.

Comment: the code is all fine.. my point was my system time zone is IST and the server time is something else like say it takes the Sweden time.. if i comment on an article it should show **few seconds ago** for **fromnow()** functionality, but it takes the server time and shows **few hours ago** how to make them dynamic and adapt user timezone..